# CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT CURL c++ error code

Tags: c++, libcurl, error-code

When using the following code I get a CURLcode result of CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT when calling the Post function.

I've had a play around with the options I'm setting but it hasn't improved anything, what would I be missing or doing wrong in this instance?

```
Question was solved. refer to the following code.
```

EDIT:
For anyone having the same issue I managed to resolve it myself. This is the code I used.

```
namespace networking
{
    CURL* curl = nullptr;
    std::string response_buffer;

    static size_t WriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
    {
        ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
        return size * nmemb;
    }

    void Setup() {

        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl == NULL) {
            return;
        }

        struct curl_slist* headerlist = NULL;

        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Accept:application/json");
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)&response_buffer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
    }

    bool PostXML(std::string url, std::string data, json& output) {

        printf("%s\n", data.c_str());
        response_buffer.clear();

        CURLcode res;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            return false;
        }

        output = json::parse(response_buffer);
        return true;
    }

    void CleanUp() {
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which function call returns `CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT`? Also, you should check **all** function results (`curl_slist_append`, `curl_easy_setopt`, etc.).

Comment: You can set the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option to 1 to get more verbose logging from libcurl. This is normally written to standard error.

Comment: You may start at numeric options, for example `CURLOPT_POST` accepts long integers, but you pass an integer.

Comment: `CURLoption::CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` - there is no such option in libcurl. You might use it from another library. Voting for close as a typo.